# Skip mvn test -B in travis ci

Tags: java, travis-ci

I'm using travis ci for [this](https://github.com/Tinwor/jemma.osgi.javagal) project. I want skip the test so in the .travis.yml I've added this:

```
install: mvn clean package eclipse:eclipse -D eclipse.pde install -DskipTests=true -Darguments=-DskipTests
```

But it always run `mvn test -B`. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build configuration is there - http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-configuration/

So you need to make "install" as empty command. Example - https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/.travis.yml#L21

Answer (score 1):

For skipping test in travis you need to put the below configuration

`install: true`

`script: mvn clean package -DskipTests=true`